# Compare each value in a list with two values in other list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to locate elements between levels using the z of the elements and elevations of the levels I have.

When an element from elemz is between two values of the list levElev I need to get the lower value (lower elevation). For example: element z = 1000 > elev (0) and < elev(4000). In this case I need to append elev(0) instead of the z 100 of that element.

So if my elevations are:

```
[-4000, 0, 4000, 9600, 17600, 26600, 33600]
```

And my elements have the following z:

```
[-3000, -4000, 1, 18000, 1000, 7000, 27000 , 33600 , 40000, 3500, 5000]
```

At the end I need the following list:

```
-4000, -4000, 0, 17600,0 ,4000 ,26600 ,33600 ,33600 ,0 ,4000
```

I have tried the following:

```
levElev = [-4000, 0, 4000, 9600, 17600, 26600, 33600]
elemZ = [-3000, -4000, 1, 18000, 1000, 7000, 27000 , 33600 , 40000, 3500, 5000]

for z in elemZ:
    lowestElev = []
    for i in range(0, len(levElev)):
        for e in levElev:
            if z >= e[i] and z<e[i+1]:
                lowestElev.append(e)
        

OUT = lowestElev
```

Comment: Do a lower bound binary search for all elements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version that works for all values:

```
levElev = [-4000, 0, 4000, 9600, 17600, 26600, 33600]
elemZ = [-3000, -4000, 1, 18000, 1000, 7000, 27000 , 33600 , 40000, 3500, 5000]

lowestElev = []
for z in elemZ:
    for i in range(0, len(levElev) - 1):
        if z < levElev[i+1]:
            lowestElev.append(levElev[i])
            break
    else:
        lowestElev.append(levElev[-1])
```

Result:

```
[-4000, -4000, 0, 17600, 0, 4000, 26600, 33600, 33600, 0, 4000]
```

The `else` trick is a great thing to know about.  It is a cool thing that Python has that not all languages do.  It says "do this if you got all the way through the iteration, never calling `break`.

Comment: thank you @Steve.. do you have a tip for getting better in more complicated lists and loops?

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding a value to the end of the elevation list and writing the following code:

```
levElev = [-4000, 0, 4000, 9600, 17600, 26600, 33600, 300000]
elemZ = [-3000, -4000, 1, 18000, 1000, 7000, 27000 , 33600 , 40000, 3500, 5000]

list = []


   
for z in elemZ:
    for i in range(0, len(levElev)-1):
            if z >= levElev[i] and z < levElev[i+1]:
                list.append(levElev[i])

OUT = list
```

Comment: This doesn't work - It gives the "right" result only because you changed the input values.  UPDATE: Oops.  I didn't notice right away that you're answering your own question.  In that case, It DOES work since it's giving you the behavior you as the OP want.  You might want to take a look at my answer though, which shows you how to do something if you go through a whole loop without your `if` ever running the code inside it. - it lets you avoid adding that extra really big value to the end of your list.